# Erro "mkdir: missing operand"

Tags: bash

Eu estou tentando criar uma série de pastas no meu computador que começam com strings de "01" a "20".

Para isso, criei uma lista de strings e apliquei o comando `mkdir` em uma iteração:

```bsh
declare -a names=("02" "03" "04" "05" "06" "07" "08" "09" "10" "11" "12" "13" "14" "15" "16" "17" "18" "19" "20")

for i in "${names[@]}"
do
    mkdir $i_txtfiles
done
```

Mas esse código não está funcionando e retorna o erro `mkdir: missing operand`.

Tentei usar o nome da pasta como string e também não funcionou. Como posso criar várias pastas no meu computador e nomeá-las com os valores de uma lista?

Comment: `mkdir $i_txtfiles`, a ideia era gerar pastas com o nome `02_txtfiles`, `03_txtfiles`, etc?

Comment: Sim. Exatamente

Comment: Então acho que deveria ser `mkdir $i\_txtfiles`, para o Bash não considerar `_txtfiles` como sendo parte do nome da variável. Ou ainda `mkdir ${i}_txtfiles`

Comment: Bom, funcionou. Eu havia tentado criar as pastas sem o "_" e também não tinha funcionado, mas agora com o escape funcionou. Obrigado

Comment: quando for assim é só trocar o comando por um echo e ver o que está sendo impresso, serve pra testar qualquer tipo de interpolação básica

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O problema está em fazer `mkdir $i_txtfiles`, pois o Bash está considerando a variável `$i_txtfiles`, que não existe, por isso o erro diz que está faltando o argumento da função `mkdir`.

Para fazer a concatenação desejada, basta vocês escapar o caractere `_`:

```
mkdir $i\_txtfiles
```

Assim o Bash entende que o `_` não faz parte do nome da variável, buscando a variável `$i` apenas.